# search for a dictionary element in an array by one of its keys

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with students data and basically want to do two things. While my implementations work, they tend to be slow as the array grows:

```
students = [{'studentid':1001,'name':'Erick','classRoom':'SA9','ranking':23},{'studentid':1009,'name':'James','classRoom':'SA1','ranking':1}]
```

I want to get a student by its id:

```
 def get_student(id):
   global students
   for student in students:
       if student['studentid'] == id:
           return student

   return False


 def update_student_rank(id, rank):
     student = get_students(id)
     if student:
        student.ranking = rank
        return student
     return False
```

The tasks are pretty much finding a specific student and operate on that specific student. When the array gets bigger, I notice it does get slow and I was wondering if there is a faster way to find a specific student?

Comment: You can use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to make it run in O(log n) instead of O(N).

Comment: @SuperStormer If there are many queries, a O(n) pre-processing + O(1) lookup might be beneficial? Though O(log n) doesn't require pre-processing. O(N+Q) vs O(Qlog n)

Comment: Actually I'm wrong about that, O(log n) requires sorting, so if it's not guaranteed, it's O((N+Q) log N) which is kinda bad - worse than mine to say

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this:

```
students = [{'studentid':1001,'name':'Erick','classRoom':'SA9','ranking':23},{'studentid':1009,'name':'James','classRoom':'SA1','ranking':1}] # Original

# Pre-pocessing takes O(n)
id_lookup = dict()
for student in students:
    id_lookup[student['studentid']] = student # Assume no collision i.e. studentid is unique

# Lookup O(1)
print (id_lookup[1001]) 
# {'studentid': 1001, 'name': 'Erick', 'classRoom': 'SA9', 'ranking': 23}
```

To do `update_student_rank` it's also easy, since you just replace `student = get_students(id)` with `student = id_lookup[id]`. (Requires global variable.)